# mysql_insert_id, does not return the last inserted id when i place it in a function

Tags: php, function, mysql-insert-id

mysql_insert_id does not return the last inserted id when i place it inside a function.

im kinda confused why it does not.

here is my code:

```
function addAlbum($artist,$album,$year,$genre) {
    $connection = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASS);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_ARTIST.'` (artistName) VALUES ("'.$artist.'")';
    $resultArtist = mysql_query($sql);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_ALBUMS.'` (albumName) VALUES ("'.$album.'")';
    $resultAlbums = mysql_query($sql);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_GENRE.'` (musicGenre) VALUES ("'.$genre.'")';
    $resultGenre = mysql_query($sql);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_YEAR.'` (albumYear) VALUES ("'.$year.'")';
    $resultYear = mysql_query($sql);
    $lastId = mysql_insert_id();
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_LINK.'` (albumsId,artistId,genreId,yearId) VALUES ("'.$lastId.'","'.$lastId.'","'.$lastId.'","'.$lastId.'")';
    $resultLink = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$resultArtist && $resultAlbums && $resultGenre && $resultYear && $resultLink){
        echo mysql_error();    
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

adam

Comment: What are all the values and what do you expect them to be?

Comment: Yeah, what do you expect to happen and what do you get?

Comment: i get a '0' value, i thought that the last insert function returns the last unique id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `mysql_insert_id()` once after four separate INSERTs, and using that ID four times for `albumsId`, `artistId`, `genreId` and `yearId`.  That doesn't seem right.

You should also check that your tables are using AUTO_INCREMENT fields.  If not, `mysql_insert_id()` will not return the insert ID.  See the docs:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

I highly recommend that you use [prepared statements](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/) with [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), perhaps via [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  It's ultimately simpler and safer.  Here's an untested example:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$stmt_artist = $dbh->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO `table_artist` (artistName) VALUES (?)'
);

$stmt_albums = $dbh->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO `table_albums` (albumName) VALUES (?)'
);

$stmt_genre = $dbh->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO `table_genre` (musicGenre) VALUES (?)'
);

$stmt_year = $dbh->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO `table_year` (albumYear) VALUES (?)'
);

$stmt_link = $dbh->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO `table_link` (albumsId, artistId, genreId, yearId) '.
    'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'
);

$stmt_albums->execute(array( $artist ));
$artist_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

$stmt_albums->execute(array( $album ));
$album_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

$stmt_genre->execute(array( $genre ));
$genre_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

$stmt_year->execute(array( $year ));
$year_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

$stmt_link->execute(array( $artist_id, $album_id, $genre_id, $year_id ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it separately for each insert, and store the result of each call separately. Like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_ARTIST.'` (artistName) VALUES ("'.$artist.'")';
$resultArtist = mysql_query($sql);
$lastArtistId = mysql_insert_id();
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_ALBUMS.'` (albumName) VALUES ("'.$album.'")';
$resultAlbums = mysql_query($sql);
$lastAlbumId = mysql_insert_id();
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_GENRE.'` (musicGenre) VALUES ("'.$genre.'")';
$resultGenre = mysql_query($sql);
$lastGenreId = mysql_insert_id();
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_YEAR.'` (albumYear) VALUES ("'.$year.'")';
$resultYear = mysql_query($sql);
$lastYearId = mysql_insert_id();
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.TABLE_LINK.'` (albumsId,artistId,genreId,yearId) VALUES ("'.$lastAlbumId.'","'.$lastArtistId.'","'.$lastGenreId.'","'.$lastYearId.'")';
```

Also, it only works if each of tables you're inserting into has `AUTO_INCREMENT` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever try to debug your code?

With `echo()` (for showing your SQL queries) or `var_dump()` (for checking the results of e. g. mysql_insert_id(), mysql_query()).

Also check `mysql_error()`.

Furthermore be sure to set the **resource identifier** in your `mysql_*()` functions. It's possible to have more than just one open MySQL resource - so be sure to identify the resource.

For example:

```
$result = mysql_query($SQL, $connection);
$lastInsertID = mysql_insert_id($connection);
```

And - it's very important to know that `mysql_insert_id()` just works with tables which have an **AUTO_INCREMENT**-field.

And what's also interesting with your code: you call `mysql_insert_id` solely after the last of 5 queries. Is this really wanted? So you only receive the ID of your last INSERT query.