# How to get the id of a row i've just inserted php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: how to get last inserted ID of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table)

I'm writing a function to add data do a database, but I then want to immediately use that entry in my code.

I know I could query: SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC

But I wonder if there's any more direct way of doing it.

Comment: You might want to have a look at an example I provided earlier for a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358531/mysql-insert-id-does-not-return-the-last-inserted-id-when-i-place-it-in-a-functi/4358609#4358609

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That mostly depends on the interface you're using to access MySQL.

If you're using PDO (recommended), you'd use `PDO::lastInsertId()`: http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

If you're using MySQL, you'd use `mysql_insert_id()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

If you're using MySQLi, you'd use `mysqli_insert_id()`: http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Just simply call whichever function is appropriate right after your INSERT completes.

It's important to note that you likely *do not* want to fetch id out of the database using SELECT because if you have multiple writers, you may get the id that some other thread inserted.  At best, you'll operate on the wrong data, and at worst, you could have serious security issues and/or corruption.

Comment: +1 Might not have been the first, but it's the most comprehensive. :-)

Answer (score 7):

With PHP you can use [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function.

Answer (score 3):

```
select last_insert_id();
```

[Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help:

[Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

> If you insert a record into a table
>   that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column, you can obtain the value
>   stored into that column by calling the
>   mysql_insert_id() function.