# Is it possible to grab the value of the primary key upon creation of row?

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the id of a row i've just inserted php/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360555/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-row-ive-just-inserted-php-mysql)

I have a form with the fields:

- Name
- Email
- City
- State
- Zip

and the user fills in with valid data... its sent to a (php) script and INSERTed into the db.

Is it possible to grab the auto-incrementing PK id WHEN submitted? E.g. say the PK id for that data I entered is '6' . How do I get this PK value programmatically (via php) upon submission? (Without having to call the last PK ID via SQL ? ) or is via SQL the only way?

Comment: Not a dup. I'm a different person, but thanks for response.

Comment: it's the same question though, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/mysql-insert-id).

Comment: Didn't even know about this. Thanks Kolink!

Answer (score 0):

Use this PHP Function:

int mysql_insert_id ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )

source:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

With **mysql_insert_id**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

```
<?php
$id = mysql_insert_id();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you've moved on to [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), `$mysqli->insert_id;` or [`mysqli_insert_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)