# INSERT with SELECT in MySQL + PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the id of a row i've just inserted php/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360555/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-row-ive-just-inserted-php-mysql)

I was wondering what's the most efficient way of inserting something and selecting it's ID property at the same time?

For example, I have a table with auto incrementing primary ID column. I insert an item into that table and I need to know the autoincremented ID for use with another table.

Right now, what I do is:

1. INSERT INTO table1 the data
2. SELECT FROM table1 the ID
3. INSERT INTO table2 another set of data along with ID.

Comment: All DB libraries I know (you give no clue of which one you are using) can fetch the auto-incremented ID from the INSERT statement. There's absolutely no need to make a SELECT.

Comment: I'm using a MySQL class I found on GitHub. I believe it's this one. https://github.com/roncli/PHP-MySQL-Class

Comment: You need to read the PHP and MySQL manuals, there are **many** examples about auto-increment ids.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this

```
INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');         --generate ID by inserting NULL
INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');  --use ID in second table
```

src: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: Will this work if I have my queries set up as follows? `INSERT INTO foo (secondcolumn,thirdcolumn) VALUES ('value1','value2')`? Notice how I omitted the auto incrementing ID column.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() (with no argument) returns a BIGINT (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value that was set for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT statement to affect such a column.

Answer (score 1):

You can try mysql_insert_id();

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php